# Angular 4/Angular 2 Azure Active Directory Authentication - Fetch token

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, angular2-services

I need to authenticate Angular 4/Angular 2 app against Azure Active Directory and fetch token code as I need to pass the Bearer token to call a REST API.

I used '**ng2-adal**' from https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal/ng2-adal-QuickStart.

Using this I can authenticate successfully. However, I need to know how to implement the below:

1. How can I fetch the Token as a string as I need to pass the Bearer token to authenticate & call a REST service?
2. How do I list the claims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How can I fetch the Token as a string as I need to pass the Bearer token to authenticate & call a REST service?

The code sample you provided implements sign in feature , if you want to get an access token , you could use `acquireToken(resource: string): Observable<string>;` function to acquire access token for resource . For example, after login, you could refer to the code below which clicks a button to acquire a token for the graph api, then you could use that token to make an api call :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AdalService} from 'ng2-adal/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: '<div protected><h1>This is the dashboard page.</h1><button (click)="logOut()">Logout</button><button (click)="callAPI()">callAPI</button></div>'
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(
    private adalService: AdalService
  ) {
    console.log('Entering home');
  }

  public logOut() {
    this.adalService.logOut();
  }
  public callAPI() {

      this.adalService.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com").subscribe(p => {
          console.log("Acquired token = " + p);

          //then you could set Authorization Bearer header and call microsft graph api 

      }, (error => {
          console.log(error);
          }));

  }
}
```

> > How do I list the claims

Do you want to get the user profile information ? If yes , you could get that from `this.adalService.userInfo`

Comment: (1) I am not using Graph Api. After getting authenticated, I need to fetch the bearer token so that U can pass it in the HttpHeader while calling a rest api. (2) Also how can I authenticate against Azure B2C AD by providing a signing policy.

Comment: 1) you could use other api by use change resource .you could fetch the access token in `subscribe` function , set header and make calls .2) please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa)

Comment: For (2), I need the Angular 4 SPA (Single Page Application) to authenticate against Azure B2C AD. I need to use the B2C AD 'Sign In' policy to authenticate by SPA. https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal/ng2-adal-QuickStart shows the authentication against Azure B2B AD but not for Azure B2B AD using a signin policy.

Comment: @Bobby , i would suggest you could start a new thread and add tag `azure-ad-b2c` since your question is not related to your original post .

Comment: @ Nan Yu - MSFT : This is noted, thanks. I have marked your reply as answer. Thanks for the help on this.